# Wristbands and nausea

Tags: clothes, nausea, motion-sickness, acupressure, acupressure-wristband

Acupressure wristbands are widely sold as a remedy for nausea caused by motion sickness. I have no doubt that they work for some people, because I experience exactly the opposite effect: elasticized wristbands, such as those found on sweatshirts, often make me feel extremely nauseous. There are some kinds of garments I simply can't wear; for others, stretching the wristbands out until they are saggy is good enough.

My two part question is this: **first**, how widely is my problem experienced by others? And **second**, is there any scientific understanding of this (apparently very real) connection between wrist pressure and the feeling of nausea?